# Integral solution (or a simpler) to consumer surplus - What is wrong?

Tags: microeconomics, supply-and-demand, consumer-theory, consumer-surplus

**Problem**

Given demand $D(p)=A-ap$, and $A,a>0$ and a fixed price $0<p_1<A/a$ by some company.

Calculate the consumer surplus and its derivative with respect to $p$. What is this number?

**My solution so far**

I could not find a simple way to do it since quantity is not known, $q_0$. I calculated the consumer surplus as

$CS=\int_{p}^{A/a}D(p)dp=\int_{p}^{A/a}(A-ap)dp=\frac{1}{2a}(A-ap)^2=\frac{(A-ap)^2}{2a}$

and its derivative as

$\frac{\partial CS}{\partial p}=\left ( \frac{(A-ap)^2}{2a} \right )=2(A-ap) \left ( \frac{\partial }{\partial p} (A-ap) \right )\frac{1}{2a}=-(A-ap)\left ( \frac{\partial }{\partial p} p \right )=-A+ap$

Which I am almost certain is incorrect. I am not sure on how to approach this without a equalibrium or am I missing it?

Comment: It seems you deleted your last post where you had used $0$ as the lower limit. Please edit the same question rather than deleting that and asking a new one.

Comment: The demand curve is linear so you don't even need to use integration and can just simply calculate the area of the triangle (as a function of the price $p$).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your calculation is correct. We can doublecheck your work with a graphical approach.

As shown in the figure below, $CS$ at some arbitrary and not necessarily equilibrium price $p_0$ is the gray-shaded area. If we take the non-integral approach, we get
\begin{equation}
CS=\frac12\left(\frac{A}a-p_0\right)D(p_0)=\frac12\left(\frac{A}a-p_0\right)(A-ap_0)=\frac{(A-ap_0)^2}{2a}.
\end{equation}
Differentiating with respect to $p_0$, we get
\begin{equation}
CS'=-A+ap_0.
\end{equation}

[image]

Comment: But if the supplied quantity at that price is $S(p_0)=q_0<D(p_0)$, the CS would not simply be this triangle, but a smaller triangle $(A/a−D^{−1}(q_0))q_0/2$ plus a rectangle $q_0∗(D^{−1}(q_0)−S(p_0)$.

Comment: @Bayesian: Good point. I guess we will also have to assume sufficient supply to meet the quantity demanded at $p_0$.

Comment: @HerrK. Thanks a lot for the help. I am having trouble on how to intepret the derivative. It is the demand at $p_1$ but with reversed sign. What does that mean.

Comment: @bymathformath: The interpretation of the derivative should be standard: If price is increased by $\$1$, then consumer surplus will decrease by (approximately) $\$D(p_0+1)$. This decrease in $CS$ can be visualized as the area of a rectangle at the bottom of the gray shaded area

Comment: @HerrK. Okay thanks! In terms of if price increase in terms of tax to $p_{1}+t$ then the new surplus is just the same formula but with this price substituted in right?

Comment: @bymathformath: Yes you are correct.

Comment: May I ask one more thing; would the change in consumer surplusbecause of a tax just be $- \Delta CS=-(CS-CS_{tax})$ and the DWL just be with reversed sign i.e $DWL= \Delta CS=CS-CS_{tax}$ ?

Comment: @HerrK.* forgot the tag.

Comment: @bymathformath: The change in CS is correct, but DWL is not. DWL has to include reduction in producer surplus and exclude tax revenue.

Comment: Hmm okay I discussed this with another user - check this https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/41267/dead-weight-loss-tax/41268#41268  (what would it look like in that case if it is not what is given in the thread because that is making me quite confused)

Comment: @HerrK. It was confused me for a week straight now so would really like a clarification of it.

Comment: But to be fair there is no mentions of supply.

Comment: @bymathformath: DWL is not equal to the full reduction in CS, because part of the reduction in CS becomes tax revenue, which is not a *loss* for society. If you're willing to assume that supply is perfectly elastic, then $DWL = CS-CS_{tax}-t\cdot D(p_0+t)$. Just draw a diagram to see this.

Comment: @HerrK. That leaves me with my assumtion and by calculation I get $\frac{at^{2}}{2}$

Comment: @bymathformath: That looks correct.

Answer (score 3):

Although your question is already answered, I am just adding a small interesting detail that might help from doing some math (especially if the demand function is rather complex):

See that (for any constant $a$):

$$f(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\int_a^x f(x)$$

Now just looking at the definition of CS, we have that $CS'=-D(p)$

Comment: Ah okay I see so in this case $CS'=-D(p_{1})$.

Comment: What does this actually mean, though. That the derivative of the consumer surplus is the opposite sign of the demand function at that point? That explanation I gave can't be useful.

Comment: I think the interpretation given by @HerrK. is sufficient. Think of the CS as area under inverse demand curve less the rectangle $pQ$. A unit increase in price decreases this by approximately $Q$.

Comment: May I ask one more thing; would the change in consumer surplusbecause of a tax just be $- \Delta CS=-(CS-CS_{tax})$ and the DWL just be with reversed sign i.e $DWL= \Delta CS=CS-CS_{tax}$ ?

Comment: @bymathformath afaik, DWL also includes loss due to change in producer surplus. As per your calculation, the lower triangle in DWL will be missed