# Dead Weight Loss (Tax)

Tags: microeconomics, consumer-surplus, taxation

**Problem**

Given demand $D(p)=A-ap$, and $A,a>0$ and a fixed price $0<p_1<A/a$ by some company.

**My solution so far**

CS is
$CS=\int_{p}^{A/a}D(p)dp=\int_{p}^{A/a}(A-ap)dp=\frac{1}{2a}(A-ap)^2=\frac{(A-ap)^2}{2a}$

**Problem**

Find the CS now with a tax $p_1+t>A/a$

**My solution so far**

Just let $p_2=p_1+t>A/a$. Insert $p_2$ into the previous result since the integration would be the same and we get
$\frac{(A-a(p+t))^2}{2a}$

**Main Problem**

Find the DWL

**My solution so far**

I get the general formulas
$(p_2-p_1)p_1-\int_{p_1}^{p_2}A-ap\;dp$ and $1/2 \cdot (p_2-p_1)\cdot (Q_1-Q_2)$
And then the answer with the second formula that

$1/2*((p+t)-p)*((A-ap)-(A-a*(p+t)))=1/2\cdot t(a(p+t)-ap)$

Is this approach correct throughout the taxation influence on CS and the DWL?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are making it unnecessarily hard for yourself. You can calculate the deadweight loss (DWL) simply as the difference between consumer surplus pre-tax and post tax, and also by adding tax revenue as it is not necessarily wasted if government uses it, so that would be:

$$DWL =  \frac{(A−ap)^2}{2a} -  \frac{(A−a(p+t))^2}{2a} +t(A-a(p+t))= A t - \frac{1}{2} \left( a t (2 p + t) \right) + t(A-a(p+t)) $$

In addition if you have further equations that explicitly model supply you should also add to the deadweight loss the difference between producer surplus pre-tax and post tax but if that is not specified it is common to assume that supply is just flat line (so there is no producer surplus).

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to learn the integral way of doing this for more complex functions in the future

Comment: @bymathformath for the integral way just subtract integral before and after

Comment: Ah okay - I see. The thing that is confusing me abit this approach is that; the previous was to find the loss in $CS$ as a cause of the tax; the next one is to find DWL. By  this approach they seem the same? (I got the loss cause of tax to $-At-atp$)

Comment: @bymathformath they should be same but in the above I think you made some small mistake somewhere (it is close to being correct but not quite - it is easier to calculate difference in two integrals than actually calculate the area of DWL

Comment: Okay so the loss in CS is $- \Delta CS$ and DWL is $\Delta CS$ ?.

Comment: @bymathformath yes exactly DWL has to be positive because it is an area and areas cannot be negative (even though it’s bad for surplus)

Comment: Okay thanks a ton. THen I must have just screwed up the calculation of the difference in CS but I think I used Wolfram. Will check again!

Comment: @bymathformath I actually double checked my calculation with wolfram too because it was already late wen I was writing it and I worried if I made some small mistake. I think above you have some small mistake in formulas for example it should be $1/2(p_1-p_2)(q_1-q_2)$

Comment: I see what I did wrong. Thanks for clearing it up and explaining the difference between loss in Surplus and DWL

Comment: Just one simple more question; the income for the state in terms of tax would just be $q \cdot (p+t)=(A-ap) \cdot (p+t)$, right? Have to compare it to DWL

Comment: @bymathformath the income for the state from tax will be just qt state does not get money from the p itself that goes to the producer.

Comment: And the quantity cant be expressed by the demand function i.e $(A-ap) \cdot t$

Comment: @bymathformath yes

Comment: I got this $\frac{A}{q}-\frac{a(2p+t)}{2q}$ which obviously shows an increase in $a$ (the slope) causes the relation DWL/Taxrevenue to be smaller. Why is that the cause?

Comment: @bymathformath it’s actually not slope per se but the fact that slope affect elasticity. DWL is created because taxes distort people’s optimal choices. However, if elasticity of demand is zero (when demand is just vertical line - its slope is infinite) then people don’t change their choices when price is changed by tax. The more inelastic demand gets the smaller DWL will be. Elasticity is not the same as slope of demand curve but slope of demand curve is part of elasticity since $El=dQ/dp p/Q$ and slope is the first term $dQ/dp$

Comment: So in short; if $a$ increases the more inelastic demand gets and thus  DWL will be smaller?

Comment: Sorry* decrease*

Comment: @bymathformath it’s actually not that simple because elasticity of demand for linear curve changes depending on price. However, the higher slope gets the less elastic demand will be at every price but if price changes it is possible that elasticity will not be higher depending on exact formula of demand.  This is why I stressed that it is elasticity what matters. Having steeper slope increases elasticity but then there are still two other terms p/Q that you need to check as they won’t be constant when you change the shape of the demand curve

Comment: I guess that is my confusion. I am having a hard time commenting on exactly the influence of $a$ on  $DWL/Tax=\frac{A}{q}-\frac{a(2p+t}{2q}$ Is this quantity known as something? All I am able to say at the moment is that an increase in $a$ would decrease the magnitude of the expression.

Comment: @bymathformath that quantity would not have special name beside what it actually is DWL to tax ratio. Also note since Q =A-ap that ratio will actually be $\frac{A}{A-ap} -\frac{a(2p+t)}{2(A-ap)}$. Also with different demand curve this expression will look differently and slope will enter differently so you have to look at case by case basis if you want to know how change in slope affects DWL/tax

Comment: Yes so all that is to say is just that, in this case, if the constant $a$ rises then the magnitude of the ratio falls.

Comment: Hey muflon, could you take a look at this one whenever you are free: https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/41339/compare-taxes-for-2-bankers-with-same-unusual-utility-function

Comment: @bymathformath hi, I seen the question but it is bit long and I am quite busy this weekend, I might come back to it later but I don’t want to make any promises

Comment: Okay sure no problem. I am not in a hurry but would like to understand it.

Comment: Hey - just a fast clarifictation. So the loss in $CS$ from a tax is $-\Delta CS$ And DWL is just the same but positiv so $\Delta CS$?

Comment: @bymathformath yes

Comment: I guess what is causing me trouble is the fact that I thought DWL would have to include the producers loss and exclude tax revenue - on top of the current CS loss

Comment: @bymathformath depends on how the problem is constructed here I assumed that there is perfectly elastic supply so all DWL falls on CS and that the tax revenue is not paid back since you don’t mention anything about supply or government in your question but otherwise yes tax itself is not part of DWL and DWL can also affect suppliers

Comment: All the info is given. We have a firm with a give demand curve and some increases in price and tax(by the government). Whould the $DWL$ be the same?

Comment: “ The change in CS is correct, but DWL is not. DWL has to include reduction in producer surplus and exclude tax revenue” I got this comment to my calculation

Comment: @bymathformath but there is no info about what supply is. Here there is just have demand and then supply is just somehow given by whatever is demanded. If you have also supply function then you should also calculate producer surplus but that is impossible here unless you withheld information about supply

Comment: There is no info at all that is why I am unsure. Only mentions the fact that the goverment taxes to a price $p_{1}+t$ and that I should find the loss in CS for the consumer. Next is the DWL. Now, would the DWL then just be that? The difference in CS

Comment: @bymathformath if you also got supply then you should definitely account for DWL on that side as well. Also you should also take into account the tax if problem says government spends it and not just ‘throws it away’ that might have been unstated assumption

Comment: @bymathformath if there is no info about supply standard default assumption is that supply is just completely flat (horizontal). In that case if you draw picture for yourself you will see there is no deadweight loss on producer side. That is actually a general result if one side of market is perfectly elastic that side of market won’t have any text burden on it

Comment: Okay correct me if I am wrong. Since no supply is given we assume it is completly flat and thus the market perfectly elastic. It follows that the DWL will just be the difference in $CS$ (Before tax minus after tax) and thus just be the result given above.

Comment: @bymathformath not market but supply. And yes plus also if the tax is used by the government you should add it in. Often this will be implicitly assumed but not always.

Comment: I guess I would have thought a portion of the difference would be taxes, though.

Comment: Supply yes* added my prievous comment before I saw yours. Would the difference then just be the above equation minus $qt=(A-ap)t$ Since that is the tax revenue

Comment: @bymathformath yes

Comment: Okay that should fix my mistakes assuming the calculation of consumer surplus from the tax being correct i.e that it is the same as before but with the new price being $p+t$ substituted in

Comment: ♦ would you be able to see this sometime? https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/41595/long-run-price-with-multiple-firms-hint-zero-profit-condition/41599?noredirect=1#comment65677_41599

Comment: @bymathformath okay I will have look at it tomorrow, also comments should not be for this sort of question unrelated requests I edited my answer above to reflect what was discussed here in the comments and then afterwards once you have read this comment move them to the chat- if you want to bring some question to my attention you can just tag me under that specific question with @ 1muflon1 (without the space) or you can open chat and tag me discretely there so it does not create unnecessary comment